# Memory allocation for primitive type which are inside class in java

Tags: java, memory, jvm

if we have a 'class A' and inside that class we have primitive data type 'int a' then for primitive type 'int a' memory will be allocated in stack area or heap area?

```
class A {
    int a;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-heap

Comment: Object instances are allocated on the heap. The field `a` is part of an object instance and therefore lives in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, primitive data types such as int, boolean, char, etc., are stored in the stack memory when they are local variables within a method or a block (including member variables of a class).

So, if you have a class A with a member variable int a, memory for int a will be allocated in the stack when an instance of class A is created. The size of the memory allocated will be determined by the size of the primitive data type, which is platform-dependent but typically fixed.